# How to modify the margins of all the article (margins refuse to budge)

Tags: margins, texstudio

I am writing an article and it has the text margins defined as:

```
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
```

At some point I wanted to introduce hyperlinks, and when I introduced the following code, the margins changed their dimensions, becoming bigger than what I had defined.

```
\usepackage{hyperref} %hipertextos
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
```

Although I have muted that package, the margins have not returned to their original position. And what is more, despite modifying the distance of the margins up to 1 cm (as can be seen in the packages), they have not changed their size.

What I can do?

```
\documentclass[13.7pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathptmx }
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
%\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{import} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{hyperref} %hipertextos
%\hypersetup{
%   colorlinks=true,
%   linkcolor=blue,
%   filecolor=magenta,      
%   urlcolor=cyan,
%   pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
%   pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
%}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
```

Comment: Could you turn this into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  I'm skeptical that hyperref is to blame, and instead suspect some other package is affecting the margins.

Comment: Did you try trashing the .aux (auxiliary) file before typesetting it again?